# Cauchy Riemann equations and complex differentiability at a point

Tags: real-analysis

If I have a complex function $f:U \to C$, and $f$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations only at one point, then does that imply that $f$ may be differentiable ONLY at that point and nowhere else?

Comment: No, for example $f(z)=1$ if the real or imaginary part of $z$ equals to $0$, or otherwise $f(z)=0$.